# Protocols must match exception while downloading large file (GWT)

Tags: xml, excel, gwt, xsd, download

I have an application where i have to generate XMl, XSD and Excel files. I will wrap all into single zip file.
My application developed with GWT, Spring and JPA. To do the download functionality i have used iframe in html page

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_downloadFrame" tabIndex='-1'
    style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
```

then i used GWT formpanel to submit the request to Servlet which actually send the request to backend.

to generate the Excel, i have used Jxl(JEXCEL) API
to generate the XML, i have used StringBuffer to prepare content then convert it Bytes. Then adding it zip.
to generate the XSD, i have used ByteArrayOutputStream then adding it to zip.

If i select only Excel, i could download the files immediately.

Background this servelt request thread is running but after sometime could see following error in browser Javascript console:

POST http://inhydsrapolu1.abc.com:9581/export/Export/exportUtility  :9581/boddesk/BodDesk/exportUtility:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://inhydsrapolu1.infor.com:9581" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match

Please help me on this

Thanks,
Saritha.

Answer (score 2):

This is a security feature. The URL in the IFRAME is a different origin than your page, which limits your page's access to its data. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.